# Hearbeat icmp configuration host aliases

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a elastic stack (version 7.3.0) configured, with a Heartbeat set up to ping my different hosts.

The config file of my monitor looks like this:

```
- type: icmp
  name: icmp_monitor
  schedule: '@every 5s'
  hosts:
    - machine1.domain.com # Machine 1
    - machine2.domain.com # Machine 2
    - machine3.domain.com # Machine 3
```

Is there a way to give the hosts an "alias" in the configuration file ?
In my organisation, the server hostname is not very meaningfull, it would be great for example to specify that `machine1.domain.com` is `MongoDB main server`.

Comment: have you had any success with suggested approach?

Comment: I wasn't allowed to change the host file, what I ended to do was use multiple configurations, and use their name to display what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The example on the [documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/configuration-heartbeat-options.html) shows that you can set host names in the hosts section/key. There they specify "myhost". So I assume that it is possible to define any name you want.

Elasticsearch is however not responsible for aliasing/resolving hostnames. It is a task of your OS.

If your heartbeat runs on a Linux machine I would set the aliases in /etc/hosts like

```
192.168.1.X mongodb-main
```

and would set the alias in the monitor config like

```
- type: icmp
  name: icmp_monitor
  schedule: '@every 5s'
  hosts:
    - mongodb-main
```

and see if heartbeat accepts it and can resolve the alias/hostname.